# Combining files into PDF produces smaller file

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a few jpg images that are around 50 MB all together, saved in PS at 12 quality. When
I combine them into a PDF with Acrobat I get a tiny 5 MB file. Now I'm new to acrobat, but I
looked around, the only size setting I could find was when combining pages > options > file size, but setting it to large didn't help. Is there some setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The only way something like that could happen is if Acrobat is changing the image quality of the JPEGs (rescaling) being inserted into the PDF.  If they drop down the dots per inch, that would decrease the size of the files being embedded in the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Your .pdf resolution is based on printing the document. You can get a brief description on it [from adobe here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7f0f.w.html).

If you saved the images from photoshop at a resolution higher than the pdf supports, acrobat will scale it down or resize it. It does this because the pdf file is optimized for **printing the whole document** based on common printer specs.